# SharpDX Create surface from bitmap

Tags: c#, directx, sharpdx, surface

I am looking for a way to get the same final output as this directx code:

surface = new Surface(device, alphaBitmap, Pool.SystemMemory);

I have to a directx wrapper like sharpDX or slimDX

but they doesn't seem to have any of the useful surface commands so I am at a loss as to how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

SharpDX and SlimDX are .NET wrappers around the native C++ DirectX interfaces. They are not based on and are independent of the DirectX 9.0 for Managed Code on which your example code is based.

To learn how to use SharpDX I suggest you clone the samples repository at

https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples

and study the examples.

Target DirectX Ver 11 and if you need to ensure that your code runs on DirectX 9 graphic cards state this requirement via the Direct3D feature levels. see( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476876(v=vs.85).aspx)